# Bat file to delete file 1 level deep

Tags: windows, batch-file, delete-file

I have my network users my documents redirected to a network drive. IE: On the server I have: Z:\ENDUSERS\enduser.name...

I'm looking to create bat file do a search from Z:\ENDUSERS for a specific file within all the enduser.name's directory (only 1 level down) and delete it. The file name is the same for all users but there is no need to search any lower than that 1st level.

Ideas/Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
@echo off
set thefile=kill.me

for /d %%d in ("Z:\ENDUSERS\*") do (
    if exist "%%d\%thefile%" (
        del "%%d\%thefile%"
    )
)
```

(replace `del` with `echo` to test)